# Threejs - creating a class, unable to pass Vector3 through position variable

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've tried to pass the position of a Vector3 into `this.positon = position;` where the position is == x, y, z.
i.e: 0, 2, 0;
`joe = new people((0, 2, 0))` 
however, it does not work. The sphere does not appear. I don't get any errors, and when I `console.log(joe)` the position = 0

```
class people {
constructor(name, age, color, position, radius)
{
    this.name = name,
    this.age = age,
    this.color = color,
    this.position = position,
    this.radius = radius,
    this.createperson()
}
createperson() // runs script below
{
    this.person = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(this.radius, 32, 16),
        new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
            color: this.color,
            metalness: 0,
            roughness: 0.5
        })     
    )
    this.person.position.set(this.position)
    scene.add(this.person)
}
```

}

`let joe = new people('Joe', 26, '#00ff00', (0, 1, 0), 2)`

but when I pass it through individually as, `this.x = x, this.y = y, this.z = z`.
`joe = new people(0, 2, 0)`
this works. It appears as it should. When I `console.log(joe)`, the position is a Vector3.

```
class people {
constructor(name, age, color, x, y, z, radius)
{
    this.name = name,
    this.age = age,
    this.color = color,
    this.x = x, // this
    this.y = y, // part
    this.z = z, // here works
    this.radius = radius,
    this.createperson()
}
createperson() // runs script below
{
    this.person = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(this.radius, 32, 16),
        new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
            color: this.color,
            metalness: 0,
            roughness: 0.5
        })     
    )
    this.person.position.set(this.x, this.y, this.z)
    scene.add(this.person)
}
```

}

`let joe = new people('Joe', 26, '#00ff00', 0, 1, 0, 2)`

Comment: `this.person.position.set(this.position)` it has to be like this `this.person.position.copy(this.position)` (`copy` instead of `set`, as you work with Vector3 here, not with separate vector values)

Answer (score 0):

let joe = new people('Joe', 26, '#00ff00', (0, 1, 0), 2)
=> let joe = new people('Joe', 26, '#00ff00', new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), 2)

and

this.person.position.set(this.position)
=> this.person.position.copy(this.position)

Comment: you're a genius, it works! thank you very much.